What does the spectral norm of a Wigner matrix converge to when the variances are not renormalised?
It seems that it is well known that for a $NxN$ Wigner matrix - that is a matrix that is symmetric (or  Hermitian, but I am only interested in the case where all the entries are real) and has i.i.d. entries with mean 0 and identical variance - the spectral radius (which in this case is equal to spectral norm) approaches 2 as $n \to infinity$  if the variances are renormalised to $1/N$ - e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.05175
But what I don't seem to be able to figure out is what happens when there is no renormalisation. I was wondering if anyone could give me any leads.

All eigenvalues diverge to infinite with order $\sqrt N$

Thanks @Exodd. That's what I actually suspected - shouldn't have written that it  should converge to anything. I don't want to ask for too much but do you know a citation/reference I could use for that result?

Terence Tao's book on Random Matrices is a good start
